# iframe's width cannot be set to auto; it remains fixed at 300px

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

As per project specifications, the sidebar is implemented as a standalone project with its own set of actions. Users can adjust the sidebar width dynamically within the range of 15px to 100vw based on their interactions.
When setting the iframe width to auto, it defaults to 300px instead of dynamically adjusting according to the width of its child elements, as required for responsive behavior.

> Is there an alternative method to set the iframe width dynamically based on child content?

**In Main Project**

```
import './App.css'

function App() { 

  return (
    <>
      <div className='bodyMain'>
        <div className='subSection'>
        Main Content
        <button onClick={() => alert("Main Project")}>Test Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     <iframe src={`http://localhost:4455?param1=${"params1"}&param2=${"params2"}`} className='sidebar' id='iFrame1'  ></iframe>     
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**In Main Project CSS**

```
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
```

**In iframe**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log("Params: ", params.get("param1"), params.get("param2"));
  },[]);

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    alert("Sidebar");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='sidebar sidebarVisible'>
        <div className='flex-style'>
          Sidebar
          <button onClick={() => onButtonClick()}>Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: why not use `width: 100%` ?

Comment: `auto` is just the inherent `width` of an object, which an `iframe` does not have (and could not, as it would allow you to glance information of its contents that might not be hosted on the same domain). A site doesn't have an `auto` width either (it's just the viewport width anyway), so I'm not sure what you expected `auto` to do here.

Comment: User should have access to both the sidebar and the main project. Initially, the sidebar width is set to "15px" with an expand icon. When the user clicks the expand icon, the sidebar width expands to "100vw" with a collapse icon.

Comment: If a sidebar should expend to 100vw then you should move it out of the normal flow in the first place such as using `position: fixed; inset: 0;`

Comment: Same sidebar will be referenced across multiple projects with identical functionality, hence the decision to implement it as a separate project.
@tacoshy "position: fixed" working but its impact the main project

Comment: Issue fixed: Using **window.parent.postMessage** to dynamically change the width with  transition.